# C++ Unsigned char array too long?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, overflow

I want to add a .dll as char array in my c++ project to inject this dll with manual map into a process without writing the dll to disk first.

So I imported the dll to HxD, exported it with C and got a big "unsigned char[] array" now which looks like this:

```
unsigned char* pSrcData = new unsigned char[2785280]
{
    0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    ...
};
```

If I build this project I get a "CL.exe exited with code -1073741571" error and another one saying "The allocated memory could not be retrieved.".

As the char array is really long I tried it with a shorter one with only 1000 Bytes and with that it worked so I guess the size of the char array is too big?

Is there a workaround? How can I add it if its too long.

Comment: One simple solution would be to store the data in binary format in a file and then read that file into the array (or vector) at run time.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit application?  2,785,280 bytes allocated from the heap in a 64-bit program should succeed with no issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver How could I do that if I dont want to read the file from disk?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am running 64 bit

Comment: Then the `new` should work, and you read the data from a file (given that the number you are giving `new[]` is correct) into the memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes the number is correct. I just checked, it also works if I do it like that: unsigned char pSrcData[27825280] = { ....};. So it might be an issue using the char* or assigning it as new?

Comment: There will be a 2.7MB static const array holding all of that data to initialize the allocated array with. Better would be `char pSrcData[] = { };` but that could still be too much data.

Comment: @BaseultBusiness `unsigned char* pSrcData = new unsigned char[2785280];` and then `read file data into pSrcData` doesn't work correctly?   Where is this declaration located?  Is it local, global?  If it's local, then your "solution" of declaring a giant array is a very risky one, since you more than likely will exhaust the stack memory.

Comment: Do not try to encode the target DLL as a byte array directly in the code at compile-time. Store the target DLL in a binary resource instead, ie via an `.rc` script that is compiled into a `.res` file, and then link that `.res` file into your final executable. Your code can then access the resource's data at runtime.